# For loop, adding 2 to an int every row printed

Tags: java, for-loop, increment

Okay, so I'm working on a program for my Comp Programming class and I need to make a program that takes the number of rows, and prints a a pyramid by adding 2 to ever row. A visual looks like this: [image: Given that the input for rows is: 5]

So the input was 5, as you see it makes 5 rows and adds 2  *'s every row down. Well, I'm not sure about how to make the number of *'s increase in increments of 2. Here is my code so far:

```
public static void pyramid(){

    System.out.println("Columns:");
    rows = input.nextInt();

    for(int s = 0; s <= rows; s++){

        for(){

        }
    }

}
```

I started another for-loop inside of the first one because I know I'm going to need it in order to make this work. My question is, how would I go about making it add 2 *'s every line it goes down.

Comment: Can you post an example of the output?

Comment: Sure, hold on one second

Comment: `Well, I'm not sure about how to make the number of *'s increase in increments of 3` Well how would you make it increase by 1? Or 2? Or any other number? You need to put in more work than just an empty for loop before coming here for homework help.

Comment: I only count one extra `*` at the start and one extra `*` at the end making two extra `*`

Comment: Think about how many spaces you need to write at the start of each line.

Comment: Surely you're adding _two_ per row, not three?

Comment: My bad, I only briefly looked at it. You're right, it is only 2 extra. But how would I go about making it add 2 *'s every row?

Comment: " I only briefly looked at it." - That's the problem right there. Please review Falmarri's comment.

Comment: Well, I mean that I quickly looked it over to see what it increments by so that I could start thinking of how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints:

For `n` rows you need to start with `(n - 1)` spaces.  Either output those spaces yourself in a simple nested loop, or use `Arrays.fill(chars, '0')` to create an array of chars that you can pass to `new String()`.  You can use `substring()` to remove one space in each iteration.

You need to start with one `*`.  For subsequent rows you *could* just do `s = s + "**"` although using a `StringBuffer` is more efficient.

FWIW, this is the best I could come up with for now:

```
static void pyramid(int n) {

    // create first line
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer(2 * n + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        out.append(' ');
    }
    out.append('*');

    // repeatedly remove a space and add two stars
    while (n-- > 0) {
        System.out.println(out);
        out.deleteCharAt(0);
        out.append("**");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The number of *s in each row is `2*s + 1`, right? So that's pretty easy to compute, by just looping up to that number within each loop, and outputting a `*` each time.

You also need to write the correct number of spaces before each set of *s though - that'll also be a function of `s` - try out a few numbers and see if you can figure out the function. Once you've got the function correct, just loop up to that number within your main loop, adding spaces each time.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an iterative approach looking at the problem (as I would recommend).  You would find that what you're looking for isn't exactly adding three to every int in the loop.

Let's start by getting the pyramid half right.  Doing this requires a simple loop.  (I'm going to run through this in Python, making it sort of like pseudocode):

```
def pyramid(rows):
    for row_num in range(1,rows+1):
        print '*' * row_num
```

This gives us the following output for 5:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

We're halfway there, what we actually need now is a mirror image starting at the middle of the pyramid on the other side.

For starters, we can figure out the number of stars per line if we look at the fact that it's always one less than two times the row number. (1,3,5,7,etc.)

This gives us the following code:

```
def pyramid(rows):
    for row_num in range(1,rows+1):
        num_stars = (row_num * 2) - 1
        print '*' * num_stars
```

Which produces the following output:

```
*
***
*****
*******
*********
```

Now the only thing we're missing is the alignment.  In order to calculate the number of spaces needed for each line to be properly indented, we can look at the pattern again.  In this case it looks like in order to center the lines, we're going to need to offset each line by a value that decreases at a rate of one per row.

The first line starts off needing four spaces before it, the second line three, etc.  So, what is that value relative to?  The number of rows themselves.

We can recognize from this pattern that the number of spaces needed to offset the output actually equals the number of rows minus the row_num.  This gives us the following code:

```
def pyramid(rows):
    for row_num in range(1,rows+1):
        num_stars = (row_num * 2) - 1
        offset = rows - row_num
        print (' ' * offset) + ('*' * num_stars)
```

Now we get our final result:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

And...we're complete!

For brevity's sake I used Python in this code example.  Since you're in a lower level language you do not have the ability to multiply a character in order to generate a string.

Many people will say "write some nested loops".  Me, I believe that it's best to write a function that mimics the higher language's wanted functionality.

If you can make a function to perform the string multiplication for you, you can use the same code twice!

If Python didn't have the built in string multiplication, you could easily work up a function such as:

```
def multiply_char(char,number_of_times):
    s = ''
    for i in range(number_of_times):
        s += char
    return s
```

Now you can use that function twice in this assignment, and keep the code looking cleaner without nested loops (which provide a readability hurtle later that a function call will not).

The way we break down these little programs in our head is half the battle of writing good code.  Your teacher is trying to get you to analyze and break the problem down into smaller bits.  It's a good idea to start from code that does something, and then iterate on it until it is functionally complete.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

To do this task you need two nested loops. First one counts number of stars needed in current row. Loops inside print spaces(to make "good looking tree") and to print stars

```
public static void pyramid(int numberOfRows){

    int curentAmountOfStars = 1; // first row has one star
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++){

        for(int j=0; j<numberOfRows-i-1;j++){ // this for prints spaces
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for(int j= curentAmountOfStars; j>0; j--){ //this one prints stars
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println(); //go to new row
        curentAmountOfStars += 2; // increase amount of stars
    }

}
```

In result You have a beautiful tree!

```
      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
  *********
 ***********
*************
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not really looking for some code to copy and paste, more of an explanation or way to go about reaching my goal. thanks for the submission regardless.

Comment: Dont give him correct answer. Its a homework so better to give him hints.

Comment: actually you can do this without nested loops.

Comment: @Alnitak how can we circumvent nested loops?

Comment: @nazar_art by using my answer

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this

1. Within the loop, add 2 to an accumulating variable.
2. Calculate the entire value of that variable by deriving the formula for length depending on the row.

The first method is likely what you will use, but the second method has a much better chance of being far more robust in future efforts.  Since this program probably doesn't have much of a future (it's a common CS 101 type homework problem) I'm guessing you'll pick #1.

```
int numAsterisks = 1;
for (row = 0; ...) {
  doStuff();
  numAsterisks += 2;
}
```

The second way is to realize that you're adding two for each row

```
numAsterisks = 2*row + 1;
```

The **major** advantage of the last technique is that subsequent values of numAsterisks cannot be wrong, even if undue factors mess up one of the intermediate values of numAsterisks.  A lesser advantage is that you don't need to store the intermediate values of numAsterisks, so you *might* also wind up with faster running code (only profiling will know for certain).

Comment: your final paragraph is only true if you don't understand preconditions and loops properly.

Comment: You can understand preconditions and loops very well, and still be subject to a coding error, someone else's coding error, or just a dumb lapse of attention at the "right" time.  The _major_ advantage of my final paragraph is that you are not dealing with a mutable data.  This opens the door to leveraging functional programming styles, which can simplify such problems.  For example, how would you distribute the processing the first example easily amongst a group of threads, without basically rewriting your program to _be_ the second example?

Answer (score -1):

I see how you are trying this but possibly a while loop would be easier and then just use string operations to create each line as you want them.

```
   public static void pyramid(){
        line=1;
        i=1;
        while(line <= 5){
                      System.out.println("*"*i);
                      i +=2;
                      line +=1;
                     }
    }
```

Also I dont know if you mean by "increase the stars by 3" do you mean that the number of stars per row would go (1,4,7,10) or accelerate by 3 like num+2, num+5, num+8 like (1,3,8,16).

If you wanted to do it the second way, this should work.

```
public static void pyramid(){
            line=1;
            i=1;
            a=3;
            while(line <= 5){
                          System.out.println("*"*i);
                          i += 2+a*(i-1);
                          line +=1;
                         }
        }
```

Comment: what exactly do you think `"*"*i` does?!

Comment: Also, you can't multiply an int with a string. But I see what you are trying to do

Comment: You'll need to be careful with this code to use `while(i <= rows*2)` not just `i <= rows`, as otherwise you'll only get half the number of rows that you want.

Comment: I am just giving a sudo example; to point him in the general direction. I work with python and in python you can do string concutination.

Comment: even as pseudocode, this is atrociously bad IMHO.  You haven't even addressed the leading spaces.